# Why am I getting 'pg_config executable not found' when deploying my web app using Vercel?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, vercel, railway

I'm trying to use Psycopg2 with Railway to connect django to postgres using this tutorial: https://dev.to/dennisivy11/easiest-django-postgres-connection-ever-with-railway-11h6.

However, I got "pg_config executable not found" when trying to deploy my django web app to Vercel.

This is what I get from Vercel:

```
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/workout_log/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-wf1ju6t6/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
      
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      running egg_info
      writing psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I installed the psycopg2-binary package in my environment but I'm still getting the same error when trying to deploy. I don't have postgresql installed on my computer because I figured I don't need it because I'm using Railway.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Either the executable is not in your `PATH`, or you didn't install the development package for PostgreSQL.

Comment: And the `requirements.txt` specifies the build-from-source version of the library judging by the error message.

Comment: Do I need to install postgresSQL on my computer even though I'm using railway? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: If it is looking for `pg_config`, it wants to know how PostgreSQL was configured and built, which typically means that it wants to compile software that links to PostgreSQL. That would certainly require PostgreSQL to be installed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? On macos I have `pg_config` in my path but still ran into this error.

Comment: @sherrellbc I never did. I ended up deploying using railway, which I recommend.